# 'as' statement angular 2 +/javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, statements

I'm using angular 6 for a web site, I would like just to know more about as statement, that I found in `FormArray`, but which is used also in other circumstances. 
My example is

`this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;`

I understand that this means that a `FormFroup` called `orderForm` has an items element and that this one is instantiated as `FormArray`, but I cannot understand the circumstances of use of 'as'.
Thank you

Comment: [Type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html)

Comment: @Rosaria Vizzini here FormArray just like a regular array so you can push & pop item and using as we are defining the type.

Answer (score 3):

The `as` keyword is used to tell the type checker to process something as another type. For example,

```
let myObj : MyClass;
let newObj: any;
...
...
myObj = newObj as MyClass;
```

tells the type checker to process `newObj` as having type `MyClass`.